# Magento2 Braintree API Call logic|code

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, paypal, payment-gateway, braintree

Where can the logic|code that makes the API call to Braintree be found?

I have found the javascript that triggers when the Continue with Paypal Button is clicked .

Magento/Braintree/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-readerer/paypal.js::payWithPayPal method.

Going with the debugger only takes me to minified non-redeable js. Beautifying the js is not of much help either.

I imagine that at a certain point an api call to braintree|paypal is made with information about the order (e.g grand total).

Where is the logic of this call found?
Should I keep looking through js files or should I start looking through php files?

Setting a breakpoint on index.php when the button is clicked does not help as the execution does not arrive at index.php ( The debugger works )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what kind of logic you are looking for. If you need frontend logic, like payment nonce retrieving, card validation, 3d secure, etc you need to dive into:

- `Magento_Braintree/js/view/payment/method-renderer/hosted-fields.js` for Braintree
- `Magento_Braintree/js/view/payment/method-renderer/paypal.js` for Braintree PayPal

If you are interested in server-side processing at first look into `Magento\Braintree\etc\di.xml` - it contains all DI configurations for Braintree integration.
As Braintree payment method based on Magento Payment Gateway, you can reed Magento of [dev docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/payments-integrations/base-integration/integration-intro.html) where all examples based on Braintree integration.

Also, check [Braintree developers documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/overview) overview, Magento Braintree integration follows it.